# Should I use the Social Plugin to log in or the Javascript SDK fb.Login method?

Tags: facebook

It seems there are at least 2 ways to implement Facebook login on a website: via the Social Plugin or the Javascript SDK.

Social Plugin (FBML):

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Javascript SDK:

```
 FB.login(function(response) { ... }, {scope: ...});
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Both accomplish the same thing as far as connecting your app to the user.

It's what you want to do after the authentication where the differences start to show.  IMO if you're going to be doing a deeper social integration I'd use the FB.login method as it is much more flexible with what you can do during the initial authentication.

Comment: Can you please give one example of "more flexible with you can do during the initial authentication"?

Comment: the fb:login plugin is pretty much a wrapper for FB.login and the syntax for FB.login is regular javascript.  For example FB.login(function(response){ if (response.authResponse) { alert('logged in'); } else { alert('not logged in'); } }); where the syntax for the plugin to accomplish the same thing isn't as elegant. i.e onlogin="alert('something')".